# Proving formula in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Give a proof of $ \vdash (\forall x)(\forall y)x=y \rightarrow (\forall y)y=y$

How could i prove this one ?

Comment: Start by figuring out what the rules of the proof system you're supposed to work in are. There are many different proof systems for predicate logic available, and we cannot help you guess which one you're supposed to use here.

Comment: In most cases, proving $\vdash(\forall y)y=y$ might be a good first step, though.

Comment: Could i apply deduction theorem and then say that $ (\forall x)(\forall y)x=y \vdash (\forall y)y=y $ So to prove this i need to prove it's tautological implication that $(\forall x)(\forall y)x=y \vDash_{taut}\ (\forall y)y=y $ then i get the abstraction of the lefthand side and the righthand side so it becomes $ p \vDash_{taut} q $ and that is true. So by soundness the original formula is true. Is that a right answer ?

Comment: x @Tennisman: Arguing via soundness is usually not considered a formal proof -- and in any case what you need in order to reason from $\vDash$ to $\vdash$ is _completeness_, not soundness. Whether that will be acceptable depends on whether you're being asked to prove $\vdash$such-and-such _at the metalevel_, i.e. show that a formal proof _exists_, or you're supposed to exhibit a concrete formal proof.

Comment: The thing is this question is on chapter which yet didn't cover proving predicate logic by Hilbert or equational style proofs. So the only thing i can work with is using deduction theorem , tautological implication and completeness. So is my answer would be acceptable ?

Comment: It's hard to prove it without predicate logic (or at least the laws of identity) ... If you reduce it to *propositional logic*, as you said, the two sentences reduce simply to $p$ and $q$, and we have  $p \nvDash_{TAUT} q$. I think that you must use the *identity axiom* : $\vdash y = y$. Form it you obtain $\vdash \forall y(y = y)$.

Comment: I don't know what rules of logic you are allowed to use, but your consequent is always true. So, anything whatsoever can be the antecedent, even something that is always false.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I can't get it at all. Can you prove it and explain it please ?

Comment: As Dan says, in first-order logic with *equality* is trivial to prove it; but when you say that you haven't "covered proving predicate logic" what are you meaning ? If you are not in *predicate logic* how are you "handling" a formula like $\forall y (y=y)$ ? Reading it in propositional logic it is only an *atom*, like $p$ or $q$; so my examples above ... Unless you are already studued the syntax of pred logic, without axioms and rules; in this case, as Dan says, the formula $\forall y (y = y)$ is valid. In this case, by completenss, it is provable: so you have $\vdash \forall y (y=y)$. 1/2

Comment: Having proved it, you can add an "assumption" whatever; so you must assert also : $\forall x \forall y (x=y) \vdash \forall y (y=y)$ and then, by the *Deduction Theorem* get : $\vdash \forall x \forall y (x=y) \rightarrow \forall y (y=y)$. But all this **does not make sense** if you do not have axioms and rules (i.e.the proof system) : *completeness* means that "if $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$". What does it mean for you $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ if you do not have a *proof system* (i.e.axioms and rules) ? 2/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You can see this question in chapter 4 in Tourlakis book. Chapter 4 didn't yet cover how to prove such formulas by hilbert or equational style proof. It's question number 9.

Comment: The exercise is at the end of Chapter 4, page 139 : **Logical Axiom Schemata of Predicate Logic**; so we assume at this point of the book to have studied *axioms* and *rules* for PL...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So can you give hilbert style or equational style proof for this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008), Chapter 4, Exercise 9, page 150 :

> > Give a proof of $\quad \vdash \forall x \forall y (x = y) \rightarrow \forall y (y = y)$.

We will use **Logical Axiom Schemata of Predicate Logic** (page 139).

We will use the following tautology :

> $\vDash_{TAUT} p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$.

Our proof will start with the following instance of the above tautology (by **Ax1**) :

> $\vdash \forall y (y = y) \rightarrow ( \forall x \forall y (x = y) \rightarrow \forall y (y = y))$

From the *identity axiom* (**Ax5**) : $x = x$ we will have the following axiom ("the set of logical axioms of first-order logic consists of all possible *partial generalizations* of the formulae in the following groups, **Ax1-Ax6**") :

> $\vdash \forall y (y = y)$.

Finally, form the two formulas above, by *modus ponens*, we will have :

> > $\vdash \forall x \forall y (x = y) \rightarrow \forall y (y = y)$.

---

***Bonus*** : Execise 8 :

> > Is $\forall x \forall y (x = y) \rightarrow \forall y (y = y)$ an instance of **Ax2**? Why?

**Ax2**, page 139, is : "This group contains all formulae of the form $\forall x A \rightarrow A[x : = t]$. It has the name *specialization axiom* but also *substitution axiom*".

Why we cannot apply **Ax2** to the formula $\forall y (x = y)$ with the *term* $y$ as $t$ ? We would have as an "instance" of the axiom the formula :

$\forall x \forall y (x = y) \rightarrow \forall y (x = y)[x : = y]$,

i.e. :

$\forall x \forall y (x = y) \rightarrow \forall y (y = y)$.

This instance of **Ax2** is incorrect (see remark page 142) because with the substitution $x := y$ the *term* $y$ has been "captured" by the quantifier $\forall$, and this kind of substitution is not allowed (see page 133, for the explanation about substitution).

In conclusion, we cannot prove it from **Ax2**; so, we need another approach in order to prove it (see above), and we know that, being *valid*, the formula is provable, by *completeness* of first-order logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof using natural deduction with a Fitch-style proof checker:

[image]

The inference rules used are universal elimination ($\forall$E), universal introduction ($\forall$I), and conditional introduction ($\to$I).

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Two usages of universal elimination works fine.  Alternatively you could use equality introduction.$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~\forall x~\forall y~x=y}{~~2.~a=a\hspace{20ex}{=}\textsf{I}\\~~3.~\forall y~y=y\hspace{17ex}\forall\mathsf I~2}\\~~4.~\forall x~\forall y~x=y~\to~\forall y~y=y\hspace{4ex}{\to}\mathsf I~1{-}3}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, that works as well. It is also simpler.